# Enviar E-mail formatado Python

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, pandas, envio-de-email, automatização

Boa tarde, estou precisando de uma ajuda em relação ao python e o pandas.

Preciso gerar um ranking semanalmente a partir de uns relatórios que extraio do sistema,
os dados eu estou conseguindo consultar porem eu preciso que eu pegue todos esses display
que eu imprimo no terminal e colocar eles formatados uma tabela ao lado da outra com a posição do ranking de cada um e enviar no corpo do e-mail com disparo automático.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas.core.indexes.base import Index
import win32com.client as win32

arquivo1 = 'TA0413-CPC.EV-Listagemgeraldeatividadedoconsultor.xlsx'
arquivo2 = 'RAA-RelatoriodeAnalisedeAgendas.xlsx'
arquivo3 = 'Validacoesdedespesas.xlsx'


ranking1= pd.read_excel(arquivo1,sheet_name='Sheet')
ranking2= pd.read_excel(arquivo2,sheet_name='Sheet')
#display (ranking1)

#Atendimentos
atendimentos =ranking1.sort_values(['Qtd. Atendimentos'],ascending=False)
display("Ranking Atendimentos",atendimentos[["Consultor","Qtd. Atendimentos"]])


#Clientes atendidos
clientes = ranking1.sort_values(['Qtd. Cliente Atendidos'],ascending=False)
display("Ranking Clientes Atendidos",clientes[["Consultor","Qtd. Cliente Atendidos"]])


#Agendas planejadas
agendap = ranking1.sort_values(['Agendas Planejadas'],ascending=False)
display("Ranking Agendas Planejadas",agendap[["Consultor","Agendas Planejadas"]])

#Agendas Realizadas
agendar= ranking1.sort_values(['Agendas Realizadas'],ascending=False)
display("Ranking Agendas realizadas",agendar[["Consultor","Agendas Realizadas"]])

# % completude de agenda

ranking1['Porcentagem']=(ranking1['Agendas Realizadas']/ranking1['Agendas Planejadas'])*100
porcentagemf=ranking1.sort_values(['Porcentagem'],ascending=False)
display(porcentagemf[["Consultor","Porcentagem"]])
 
 #Quantidade de serviços
servicos= ranking1.sort_values(['Qtd. Serviços'],ascending=False)
display(servicos[["Consultor","Qtd. Serviços"]])


#Rtr Gerados
rtr = ranking2.groupby(["Usuário"]).sum("RTR Gerado")
display (rtr.sort_values(by=["RTR Gerado"],ascending=False)[["RTR Gerado"]])




# Integração com o Outlook
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
# Email
email = outlook.CreateItem(0)
# Info Emails
email.To = ""
email.Subject = "Teste disparo de email"
email.HTMLBody = f""" 
<p>Olá Lucas, esse é o</p> 
<p>teste do email automatico em phyton.</p> 
<p>Deu certo.</p> 

<p>Ass:</p>
"""
email.Display()
email.Send()
print("Email Enviado")
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas tem o método **.to_html()** para converter cada tabela em HTML e você adicionar ao relatório.

Já testou esse método?

Comment: Não conhecia esse método, vou dar uma olhada aqui. Muito obrigado.